# Silverlight ListBox with ObservableCollection<T> and dynamic filter

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7

Lets say I have this class:

```
public class MyData
{
    public bool IsActive{get;set;}
    public String Data1 {get;set;}
    public String Data2 {get;set;}
}
```

and an

```
ObservableCollection<MyData> data = new ObservableCollection<MyData>;
ListBox.ItemsSource = data;
```

Adding items to the ObservableCollectionworks as expected; however, I want to make sure that my listbox only displays items where `IsActive` is set to 'true' -- I can't use a Linq query to set the ItemsSource because then its not an ObservableCollection, its IEnumerable and does not do any update notifications to the listbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your answer is CollectionViewSource.  Instead of binding to the list, bind to an instance of CollectionViewSource.

A slightly degenerate example follows (I am not sure if you're using ViewModels, Locators, etc to resolve your data and your list.)

Assume in your markup you have a CollectionViewSource declared in your resources as follows:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="src"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Then your list binding looks like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource src}}">
```

Finally, in code you can marry your list and your collection view source:

```
        var collectionView = this.Resources["src"] as CollectionViewSource;
        // Check for null, etc.
        collectionView.Source = observableCollectionThatIAmBindingTo;
        collectionView.View.Filter=new Predicate<Object>(o => ((ItemType)o).IsActive );
```

Additionally, you may want to check out Bea Stollnitz' articles on the topic at:

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=392

Comment: This compiles, but it doesn't display any of my items (I verified there are both IsActive=True and IsActive=False in the collection) Any thoughts on what to try?

Comment: It appears to work without teh View.Filter part. Althought the Predicate seems to be OK...

Answer (score -1):

The easier way is to use `Visibility` in XAML.

Supposed your `ListBox` `ItemTemplate` use `StackPanel` to hold your data, and in this case you have 2 `TextBlock` inside this `StackPanel` (1 for Data1, 1 for Data2).

So you should bind this `StackPanel`'s `Visibility` with **IsActive**