# WP7 how to filter listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, search, filter, listbox, real-time

I have a `ListBox` which have about 100 items. Now I want to to filter this `ListBox` based on what user types in `TextBox`. I want to search real time, so I handle `TextBox_OnTextChanged` event.

My first solution was to set `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` whenever text changed. This is really slow.

[Many ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295948/how-to-implement-search-in-listbox-wp7) suggest using `CollectionViewSource`, but this doesnot make it faster.

How to filter `ListBox` **real time** and **fast** ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the filter methode of databinded source

[Silverlight ListBox with ObservableCollection<T> and dynamic filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732145/silverlight-listbox-with-observablecollectiont-and-dynamic-filter)

Comment: Yama mato. Yes, you're right, it needs a workaround. The current answer could be easier. thx.

Comment: Here is the workaround http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-DataGrid-Control-for-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-Part-1.aspx

Comment: Have your tried my link in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732145/silverlight-listbox-with-observablecollectiont-and-dynamic-filter ?

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, I used CollectionViewSource, it is OK, but I want to search based on what user types (OnTextChanged event, which mean I must update the Filter), and it works really slow. Is there a better way ?